# How to change the sequence of Sessions and Users in Acquisition

Tags: google-analytics

How can I change the sequence of Users and Sessions in Acquisition Tab? Earlier it was in proper sequence. Like - Sessions, & New Sessions & Users. But now it has been changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the order of columns in a default report in Google Analytics.
What you can do is: click on the edit button to create a new custom report based on the current one, and make the desired changes.

Recently, there was an update on GA that changed the default metrics to be user-based instead of session-based. You can revert this default by editing the property's configurations.